# Как организована память в std::deque?

Tags: c++, алгоритм, stl

Для лучшего понимания устройства контейнеров решил их все реализовать. И вот столкнулся с проблемой на *std::deque*.Принцип двусвязной очереди понимаю, но не понимаю как устроена стдшная дека, а именно: как она может выполнять добавление элементов с обеих сторон за O(1) и при этом же иметь скорость произвольного доступа так же O(1). Все знакомые программисты говорят что стдшная дека реализована как двусвязный список, элементы в котором - блоки фиксированного размера, но тогда каким образом произвольный доступ O(1)?(как минимум, что-бы дойти до нужного блока я потрачу энное время). Вот такой вот вопрос.

Comment: Ну там блоки можно хранить не в списке, а в другом векторе с кол-вом элементов. Тогда поиск нужного элемента по индексу - это просто смотрим в первом векторе диапазон, а потом уже в целевом блоке. Если блоков не очень много, то все будет достаточно быстро.

Comment: я бы предложил использовать обычный вектор и заполнять с середины(!) поддерживая расширение как в обычном векторе но с 2 сторон.

Comment: @KoVadim вы по сути предложили обычный вектор. Блочность системы ни даёт преимуществ в этом случае.

Comment: Векторная реализация будет включать в себя  перевыделение памяти, что уже сделает добавление в в конец или начало(!) точно не O(1).

Comment: @WhoAreYou если вы мне, то как бы нет.

Comment: Нет, я предложил дерево с одним уровнем вложенности

Comment: @pavel расширение в векторе подразумевает же перевыделение памяти и копирование элементов

Comment: @KoVadim я понял идею. Кстати можно в ноду 1 элемент кидать, ещё и удобнее будет.

Comment: @WhoAreYou ну обычный вектор это тоже делает, но добавление в конец у него O(1). Тут просто аммортизированные операции идут.

Comment: @pavel спасибо, я это не учел

Comment: @pavel но тем не менее, на cppref:В отличие от std::vector, элементы deque не хранятся непрерывно: обычно реализован с помощью набора выделенных массивов фиксированного размера.

Хранилище deque обрабатывается автоматически, расширяясь и сужаясь по мере необходимости. Расширение deque дешевле, чем расширение std::vector, потому что оно не требует копирования существующих элементов в новый участок памяти.

Comment: @WhoAreYou тогда как писал KoVadim. Представьте обычное динамическое дерево и применённой оптимизацией сжатия путей.

Comment: Если интересно разобраться с контейнерами и другими частями стандартной библиотеки, то рекомендую прочитать книгу [«The C++ Standard Library»](http://scrutator.me/post/2015/02/04/cpp_standard_lib_2nd.aspx). Как минимум первое издание этой книги есть на русском. Там рассмотрено и устройство `std::deque`, в том числе.

Comment: @ixSci спасибо большое

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Реализация `std::deque` не является секретом - ее можно посмотреть в [сорцах](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/bits/stl_deque.h). Но там немного мрак для неподготовленного человека. Но есть в картинках http://cpp-tip-of-the-day.blogspot.com/2013/11/how-is-stddeque-implemented.html

Если кратко - есть две реализации - вектора объединяются в связанный список и вектор векторов.

Вот [на SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5728359/stl-internals-deque-implementation) как раз и подтверждают, что реализации используют вектор векторов, причем внутренние вектора фиксированного размера.

А вот [в переписке gcc](https://gcc.gnu.org/ml/libstdc++/2014-01/msg00112.html) обсуждают возможность использования циклического буфера.

и ещё немного картинок и текста - https://www.quora.com/What-is-a-possible-implementation-for-std-deque

Comment: ага. По сути очередь на 2 стеках. Из этой области всё.

Comment: да спасибо, сейчас ознакомлюсь. Исходники пытаюсь читать уже дня 2 подряд, но что то плохо заходит такое чтиво(